# while selecting a row in uitable, It says "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array"

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

The Problem is:

I need when a Pushbottom is clicked, the next row will be selected, the related code is:

```
function pushbutton11_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   global mtable;
   jScroll = findjobj(mtable);
   jtable=jScroll.getViewport.getView;
   row = jtable.getSelectedRow ;
   jtable.setRowSelectionInterval(row+1,row+1);
   jtable.setColumnSelectionInterval(0,99); %the number of mtable columns is 100
```

and in the `openningFunction` I `mtable` as bellow:

```
mtable = uitable('parent',gcf,'Units','normalized','Data',data);
set(mtable,'columnName',cname);
set(mtable,'Position',[0.17 0.2 0.75 0.75]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly `jScroll` is empty when `findjobj` fails. And *this* can happen because you're using global variables!

Please, please, for the love of all that is good and holy, don't use global variables; they cause exponentially more pain than they will ever be able to prevent.

Anyway, try removing the semicolon at the end of this line

```
jScroll = findjobj(mtable)
```

and see what the output is when the error occurs. If what I say is indeed true, you can circumvent it by something like

```
jScroll = findjobj(mtable);
if ishandle(jScroll) %// <-- add this line
   jtable=jScroll.getViewport.getView;
   row = jtable.getSelectedRow ;
   jtable.setRowSelectionInterval(row+1,row+1);
   jtable.setColumnSelectionInterval(0,99);
end %// <-- and this one
```

(which is anyway a good prcatice with anything that is *supposed* to be a handle

Does that help at all?